# Most common and important SQL commands that solely apply to MyIsam storage engine?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam, mariadb

It has been recently come up into one of our discussions that moving an old legacy system using old MyISAM based MySQL deployment can't be easily replaced by an InnoDB based MySQL or MariaDB deployment. The reason that came up was that there were too many MyISAM only SQL commands all over the place. I haven't seen the code yet so I'm wondering what SQL commands where they referring to.

I only know of SEVERAL like below which are associated with table locking. It will probably work with InnoDB still in theory, but more appropriate for MyISAM , `MERGE`, and `MEMORY` storage engines which support table locking.

```
LOCK TABLES
UNLOCK TABLES
```

If there are more, or point me to a collection of it. It will be highly appreciated.

*--edit--*

I'll put everything else I find below this line.

```
MATCH (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LOCK TABLES` for an InnoDB table too, so that's not MyISAM-specific.  Though it's unnecessary to lock InnoDB tables.  It's preferable to use transactions, MVCC, and `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`.

There are a number of configuration variables and status variables that are relevant only for MyISAM, such as `key_buffer_size` to dedicate some memory to caching indexes.  But these are not commands.

A couple of features of MyISAM tables aren't supported by InnoDB.  One is grouped auto-increment primary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  group_id INT, 
  position INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, position)
);
```

The table above increments `position` as you insert rows, but starts over at 1 for each distinct value of `group_id`.  This works only in MyISAM.

`CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX`, and hence the `MATCH()...AGAINST()` query predicate are currently supported only in MyISAM.  But these are being implemented for InnoDB in MySQL 5.6.

`CREATE SPATIAL INDEX` is supported only in MyISAM.

`CHECKSUM TABLE` applies only to MyISAM tables.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is in some ways specific to MyISAM, but when you run this command against an InnoDB table, it's automatically translated to a recreate + analyze operation.

`CREATE TABLE` options that are supported only by MyISAM:

- AVG_ROW_LENGTH=nnn
- DATA_DIRECTORY=path
- INDEX_DIRECTORY=path
- DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1
- PACK_KEYS=1
- ROW_FORMAT=FIXED

The MERGE storage engine can merge only MyISAM tables.

My favorite command to apply to a MyISAM table is the following.  :-)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer create a "temporary" table, insert/update and delete, drop the old table  and than rename the new table to the old name.

otherwise you can in the last step

```
TRUNCATE TABLE x;
INSERT INTO x SELECT * from temp_x;
```

Comment: You are talking about a migration strategy. I am talking about what SQL commands are specific to MySQL+MyISAM combination.